# two different operation in different cases sql table function

Tags: sql, differential-equations, operation, table-functions

I want to program a function that sees how much time the client spent of time without paying the seller. My problem is that I'm kind of confused because this is the function that already programmed:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[bal_cli](@date date, @diff1 int,@diff2 int) returns @table1
table 
(
  solde float,
  cpt char(20)
)as

begin

insert into @table1(solde,cpt)
SELECT         SUM(a.ECRDEBIT-a.ECRCREDIT) AS solde,a.CPTCODE
  FROM            dbo.ECRITURES AS a , dbo.ECRITURES AS b
  WHERE      (a.JORID = '7' or a.JORID = '10' or a.JORID = '22' or a.JORID = '15' or a.JORID = '16' or a.JORID ='5' or a.JORID = '38' or a.JORID = '45' or a.JORID = '12' or a.JORID = '17' or a.JORID = '44' or a.JORID = '18' or a.JORID = '8' or a.JORID = '9') AND (a.ECRISMARQUE <> 'O') AND (a.CPTCODE LIKE '3421%') and 
                           ( DATEDIFF(day, a.ECRDATEEFFET, @date) >= @diff1 and  DATEDIFF(day, a.ECRDATEEFFET, @date) < @diff2) and (YEAR(a.ECRDATEEFFET) = YEAR(@date)) 

  GROUP BY a.CPTCODE

return;
end;
```

My issue is that I want JUST for JORID to calculate the difference note with ECRDATEEFFET but with ECRLIBELLE.

Comment: When you are writing the question, you have a preview just below the box where you are typing. You can check the formatting there before you post.

Comment: why is the b table never used???

Comment: Start using 'modern' explicit `join` syntax

Comment: @FranckNgako sorry just forget the b table  i was just thinking about a stupid solution

Comment: @HoneyBadger i didn't understand

Comment: @AzouzRh, never use comma's in your where clause (implicit join), rather use `JOIN`: `FROM dbo.ECRITURES AS a (LEFT|RIGHT|INNER) JOIN dbo.ECRITURES AS b ON a.ID = b.ID` (or whatever the join condition are). This is just general advice, not specific to your question.

Comment: @HoneyBadger ohhh okay thanks man ...